# How to merge these two arrays in this specific order

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array as following

```
Array
(
    [0] => 641
    [1] => 622
    [2] => 100
    [3] => 6431

)

Array
(
    [0] => 64.1
    [1] => 62.2
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 643.1

)
```

How can I make it as following

```
Array
(
    [0] => 641  
    [1] => 64.1
    [2] => 622
    [3] => 62.2
    [4] => 100
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 6431
    [7] => 643.1

)
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
$result=array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

**Note:** Your values wont be in the order you presented though. If that is important then you need to loop through your arrays to build a new array accordingly.

Ummm ok here is that version as well

```
if(count($array1)==count($array2))
{
     for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++)
     {
        $result[]=$array1[$i];
        $result[]=$array2[$i];
     }
}
print_r($result);
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/WH6cVOuf)**

**[Manual](http://www.php.net/array_merge)**

Comment: array_merge can't helped me !!

Comment: Ok see the second version that presents the output like you want. Had a few extra minutes  :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_merge()` function merges one or more arrays into one array.

example:

```
array_merge(array1,array2,array3...)
```

Comment: Did you saw the final array ?